# PyQGIS data defined property for label orientation

Tags: qgis, labeling, pyqgis-3

I have a `QgsVectorLayer` object with field `Direction` which determines orientation of the symbol of the layer.  I use `setDataDefinedproperty` method to adjust the orientation of the symbol like:

```
symbol = vLayer.renderer().symbol()
symbol.symbolLayer(0).setDataDefinedProperty(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyAngle,QgsProperty.fromField("Direction"))
```

Now I want to add label for `Name` field with same orientation as symbols. I tried :

```
label_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
label_settings.fieldName = "Name"
label_settings.enabled = True

label_property_collection = QgsPropertyCollection()
label_property_collection.setProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.TextOrientation,QgsProperty.fromField("Direction"))
label_settings.setDataDefinedProperties(label_property_collection)

labels = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(label_settings)
vLayer.setLabeling(labels)
```

But there is no change for label orientation. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QgsPalLayerSettings` enumerator needs to be not `TextOrientation` but `LabelRotation`

```
label_property_collection.setProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.LabelRotation,QgsProperty.fromField("Direction"))
```